# Save data in a form using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `form` tag when user can add new inputs every time when clicks on `add field` button. Also near the inputs appears `edit` button. Clicking on `edit` button the inputs should disappear and instead of them should appears `edit` text. 
**Issue**: When i click 2 times on `add fields` button and after that i click on one of `edit` button from the form, the both forms disappear and instead of on `edit` text appears 2, for both form.

**Question**: How to solve the issue above, and when i will click on one of edit button only that section should change into `edit` text, but rest should still as input?

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const [editF, setEdit] = useState(false);
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
    setEdit(true);
  };
  const edit = () => {
    setEdit(true);
  };

  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map(field =>
                editF === false ? (
                  <Space
                    key={field.key}
                    style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                    align="start"
                  >
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "first"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                      rules={[
                        { required: true, message: "Missing first name" }
                      ]}
                    >
                      <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "last"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "last"]}
                      rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing last name" }]}
                    >
                      <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                    </Form.Item>

                    <button onClick={edit}>edit</button>
                  </Space>
                ) : (
                  "edit"
                )
              )}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-monad-kzjbe?file=/index.js:719-739

Comment: You have just one `editF` that you use for all your fields, so if the condition is true for one it's true for all of the fields.

Comment: @po.pe, what could be the solution in my case?

Comment: I haven't used AntD and don't know it's restrictions, but a solution would be to differentiate between the different targets of the edit button and set the attribute for edit individually.

Answer (score 0):

Here a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-volhard-4uzj5). Essentially, you just need save in state some array of id fields which toggled to edit mode. I suppose, in your case `index` will be enough. But don't forget, using indexes as id or key is a bad thing. In most cases you need specify id more deeply.

Comment: it works, but also i want to ask you in the next case: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-surf-uumrp?file=/index.js , when i will click on `submit` button to get the same logic like on edit button, plus to get the values from form? Please, tell me if i explained clear the target.

Comment: could you help?

Comment: When you clicking on `submit` button in a row do you want to get values only from triggered row or whole form?

Comment: If i get your ask correctly, you want something [like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-night-g9eyu?file=/index.js), but do you really need it? It's look strange. In real apps i've never had real cases for that.

Comment: `When you clicking on submit button in a row do you want to get values only from triggered row or whole form? `, i want to get values just from that form where i click,

Comment: I really recommend you to look at the ant/react-hook-form/formik docs and get all common cases with using forms in the Web. If my answer helped, please mark it as correct. Good luck, i have to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a state variable called `editF` and every variable is depended on it since your code states: `editF === false ? (....):edit`

So once `editF` is false all fields disappear.

Try to make a list that has a boolean type variable for each field, then map it to number of fields you have and their edit/not edit state.

Comment: could you show please, on my example, because i don't understand very good the idea. Thanks